# Bedrooms aren't being heated as well after new furnace

Tags: heating, windows, ducts, floorheating

When my bedroom doors are closed the room is cold. We replaced our furnace about 5-10 years ago and the repair person said we didn't need as big a unit as we had before and every since then it feels cold in the bedrooms and sometimes in the living room.  It's a small 900 sq foot rancher. What should I do?

Comment: Vents open? Cold air returns unobstructed? Vents partially closed in other rooms? Furnace filter clean?

Comment: All vents are open, filter is changed regularly.  Not sure about the cold-air returns, where would they be located?

Comment: Should be fairly obvious--they're vents that typically don't have closer mechanisms. Usually opposite from the supply vents, either vertically or horizontally.

Comment: OK, then it's in the hallway where the filter is so I'm guessing that there is another filter on the furnace which is under the house.

Comment: There's a filter on your return vent? That's probably so you don't have to enter the crawl space to change it. I'd verify, though.

Comment: I really appreciate all the help...I think I'm going to like this app. My husband may hate.

Answer (score 1):

All of the air that blows out of your vents to heat or cool a room has to go somewhere.  That somewhere is the large air return vent.  When you close the door to a room, and there's not much of a gap under the door, the air blowing from the vents doesn't have any where to go (you just sealed the air's access to the return vent which is probably in a hallway or large common room), so the result is more air coming out of vents in other, non-closed-up rooms, and very little air coming out in the closed room.

The easiest solution is to not close the door all the way.  If you really need the door closed, you can trim the bottom of the door to give a larger gap, or put a vent in the door itself.

Comment: We usually keep the door open most of the time. There is a very small crack under the doors so I am guessing that is not sufficient.  Will changing the location of the vents to the ceiling help?

Comment: It doesn't matter where the vents are.  If there's not enough of a gap for all the air coming out of the vents to escape the room, you're going to have less heat (or cooling) than you should.